# EAV with very few of each entity

Tags: postgresql, eav

I have data that fits an entity-attribute-value structure but with very few entries (same attributes but different values) per entity.

The main characterizations of my data are as follows:

- ~700 different entity types, but only 3-4 entries  for each type.
- ~1400 attributes, but only 2 including the id are used for every type.
- ~75% of the attributes are unique to a type, but a substantial number are used for many types.
- The data will be very static, very rarely requiring changes.
- Queries will primarily consist of filtering on attributes.

Based on my use-case and the fact that there will only be a few thousand entries total, my initial thought is to use a single table inheritance model.  That said, the sparsity of the table leaves me wondering if jsonb or hstore or something else I haven't thought of might be a better solution.

I'm using Postgres 9.5

Comment: Sounds like a good fit for a `hstore` column.

Comment: Or a `jsonb` one, and then you already answered your question :)  I think, `jsonb` has a richer set of functionality around it that `hstore`, so I'd possibly use the former.